# passing multiple column to function for fixing outlier

Tags: r, outliers

```
summary(standard_airline)


#outlier treatment
outFix  <- function(x){

      quant <- quantile(x,probs = c(.25,.75))

      h     <- 1.5*IQR(x,na.rm = T)

      x[x<(quant[1]-h)] <- quant[1]

      x[x>(quant[2]+h)] <- quant[2]

}

 v  <- colnames(airline[,-1]) 

 data2 <- lapply(v,outFix)
```

[image: dataset columns]

> Error -  Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I couldn't find out what is the error coming here although logically seems right, Is there any way in R to pass multiple column of a dataset to a particular function. Here I want to pass every column except ID to fix the outliers.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The issue you are encountering is that `v` is a character vector of column names. Your function `outFix` expects a numeric vector. So what your `lapply` code is actually doing is something like this: `outFix("Balance")`. So it's trying to compute quantiles and IQRs on a string, which is why you're having your error.

```
quantile("Balance")
Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

---

**Solutions**

In the following code replace `df` with `airline` for your specific data.

In base R:

```
df[,-1] <- lapply(df[, -1], function(x) outFix(as.numeric(x))) # exclude first column
```

Or using your code:

```
df[, v] <- lapply(df[, v], function(x) outFix(as.numeric(x)))
```

---

Using `dplyr` you can apply your function to every column and except `ID` with:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(dplyr::vars(-ID), ~ outFix(as.numeric(.))) # remove ID by name

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(-1, ~ outFix(as.numeric(.))) # remove ID by column position
```

This makes sure that all your columns are numeric before being passed to your function `outFix`.

If you're certain that all of your columns are numeric ahead of time then you don't need to use the `as.numeric` function, but could be good to have in case.